# Reading Database inside config file in codeiginter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, paypal, config

I'm integrating paypal following this link https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/. Everything is working fine there is no problem at all. But I have to write paypal's account email in config file of paypal. I want to give choice to Admin so that he can change paypal account. I tried to access database inside cofing file but it gave error. config file for paypal is following

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Paypal library configuration
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

 // PayPal environment, Sandbox or Live
 $config['sandbox'] = TRUE; // FALSE for live environment
 $paypal = $this->db->where('set_id',1)->get('settings')->row_array();
 // PayPal business email
 $config['business'] = $paypal['paypal_accnt'];

 // What is the default currency?
 $config['paypal_lib_currency_code'] = 'USD';

 // Where is the button located at?
 $config['paypal_lib_button_path'] = 'assets/images/';

 // If (and where) to log ipn response in a file
 $config['paypal_lib_ipn_log'] = TRUE;
 $config['paypal_lib_ipn_log_file'] = BASEPATH . 'logs/paypal_ipn.log';
```

how can i achieve this. any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/ancillary_classes.html?highlight=ci%20instance#creating-ancillary-classes

Comment: Thanks, it really helped.

Comment: feel free to self answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

`$this` Works in controllers to access methods. We cannot use `$this` in outside of controller class. So Use

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
// etc.
```

It works.
For more details visit [user_guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/ancillary_classes.html?highlight=ci%20instance#creating-ancillary-classes)